# Tf.Dataset with Keras returning a ValueError

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

Getting a ValueError related to shape when passing Tensorflow Dataset into a Keras's model.fit function.

My dataset's X_train has shape (100 samples x 62 features) and Y_train is (100 samples x 1 label

Reproducible code below:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Sequential, optimizers
from tensorflow.data import Dataset

num_samples = 100
num_features = 62
num_labels = 1
batch_size = 32
steps_per_epoch = int(num_samples/batch_size)

X_train = np.random.rand(num_samples,num_features)
Y_train = np.random.rand(num_samples, num_labels)

final_dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, Y_train))

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu',input_shape=(num_features,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(final_dataset,epochs=10,batch_size=batch_size,steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (62,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Why is the dense_input getting an array with shape (1,)? I am clearly passing it an X_train of shape (n_samples, n_features).

Interestingly the error goes away if I were to apply a batch(some number) function to the dataset, but seems like I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It's an intended behavior.

When you use Tensorflow Dataset , you shouldn't specify the `batch_size` in the fit method of 'Model'. Instead as you mentioned you have to generate the batches using the function with tensorflow dataset.

As mentioned here in the documentation

> batch_size: Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32. **Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, dataset, dataset iterators, generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate batches)**.

The classical behavior is therefore to do as you did: generate the batches with the dataset.
Also use `repeat` if you want to perform multiple epochs. On the `.fit` side you'll have to specify the `steps_per_epoch` to indicate how many batch is one epoch and `epochs` for your number of epochs.